# Euler's Formula To Show 2E=3V

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, convex-geometry

I have this question:

"Consider a convex polyhedron, all of whose faces are square or regular pentagons. Say there are m squares and n pentagons. Assume that each vertex lies on exactly 3 edges"

Then I want to show that $3V=2E$ ! I can draw a picture and understand why it is true but I was wondering whether there was a more "mathsy" way of going about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sentence in the original problem is the only one that matters. From each vertex you have 3 edges. If the edges would not be connected at both ends, you will have $3V$ edges. Since each edge is connected to two vertices, the number of edges is $E=\frac{3V}2$.

To check that this is true in other cases, see a tetrahedron, with $V=4$, $E=6$, or a triangular prism $V=6$, $E=9$.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!